# Java Makefile "No rule to make target"

Tags: java, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile for my java program. I've tried looking online and this is what I've come up with.

```
JFLAGS = -g

JC = javac

JVM = java

FILE=

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:

        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = banker.java

MAIN = Main

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

run: classes
    $(JVM) $(MAIN)
```

I am getting an error that says

```
No rule to make target 'banker.class', needed by 'classes'. Stop.
```

I only have one class: banker.java

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but why would you want to use a Makefile? (instead of something like Gradle, Maven, or Ant?)

Comment: It is very unusual to use Make to build Java projects. Any particular reason why you want to use Make? If not, you are much better off with something like Ant, Maven (or one of the many other Java-based tools).

Comment: It's for a homework assignment. My professor wants to run in on the penguin server.

Comment: The formatting of a makefile is important. Please ensure that the makefile in your post accurately represents the makefile you have locally. Specifically in indentation. Correctly indented (and with leading tabs on the recipe lines) this looks, at first glance, like it should work.

Comment: The formatting is the way it is in my Makefile. Same error. Thanks for all the responses though

Answer (score 1):

It looks like banker.java isn't in the same directory as the Makefile.

If not, you need to instead say: "CLASSES = relative/path/to/banker.java"

So, for example, if you have a directory structure like this:

```
MyProject
   -jsrc
     -banker.java
   -jbin
   -Makefile
```

and your banker.java is in MyProject/jsrc, then you need to change

```
CLASSES = banker.java
```

To be

```
CLASSES = jsrc/banker.java
```

And, unless you want the .class files to also be in jsrc, you need to change

```
$(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java
```

to

```
$(JC) -d $(JCLASSDIR)/. $(JFLAGS) $*.java
```

And add

```
JCLASSDIR=jbin
```

At the top

```
JFLAGS = -g

JC = javac

JCLASSDIR=jbin

JVM = java

FILE=

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:

        $(JC) -d $(JCLASSDIR)/. $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = jsrc/banker.java

MAIN = Main

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

run: classes
    $(JVM) $(MAIN)
```

Comment: No rule to make target `classes', needed by `default'.  Stop.